# Img Src on local computer

Tags: html, image, local

I imagine that this is a common beginner question, but I've found no responses that quite cover my problem: I am having trouble linking to an image on my local computer.

I'm working on making a theme for a wordpress installation (on a Dell running Windows 7 using Xampp.) My `index.php` file is located at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\wordpress\wp-content\themes\LeftColumn\index.php
```

and the image I want to show is at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\wordpress\wp-content\themes\LeftColumn\images\pmsplogo.jpg
```

... and while I've tried many variations, somehow nothing I put in the `<img src=""/>` seems to be working. Can anyone explain what the right way to code this is for my situation?

Just to note, it will properly display an image from an external website (such as: http://littlewebhut.com/images/eightball.gif)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Generally IE is OK with a path like `C:\`, but other browsers need something more.  Start the path with `file:///C:/` and then fill in the rest of the path to the file through Windows Explorer.

But it might be best to consider relative paths - `../../images/src="img.gif"` - for example.  This would be two directories up from the current location, and then into the images directory.

Comment: I'm in agreement that it would be best to use (and be in the habit of using) a relative url, for later portability... just haven't found one that works yet, see my comment to Stepo, above.

Answer (score 1):

Paths to files in HTML are from the web root. So `\tutorials\wordpress\wp-content\themes\LeftColumn\images\pmsplogo.jpg` is the same on your local computer and remote server. If it isn't working then you need to make sure your paths are correct and you have set up both servers correctly.

Comment: Actually at this point, I'm only using my local computer - no remote server... might I have set something up incorrectly? (But then why does it work to display the eightball.gif image?)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>` in front of the actual path. Let's suppose that you have a `logo.png` image in a folder called `images` in your theme. To link it in a Wordpress theme (index.php or other wordpress template pages) you do something like this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
```

The above php function (`bloginfo`) is calling for your template url. To this template url you need to add where the file actual file is in your theme (in this case `/images/logo.png` ).

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not necessary** to **write whole path** in frame of template. This should suffice: `\images\pmsplogo.jpg`

Here's screen of my WordPress template, It's working very fine with entry described above:

- http://stepolabs.com/upload/path.png

If you were moving the template, you wouldn't need to change path of each img. It's big advantage.

Comment: your example included some php, which mine currently doesn't... not sure if that makes a difference here, but I tried <img src="\images\pmsplogo.jpg" /> , and it didn't work... any thoughts?

Comment: ok... the plot thickens here... I _can_ link to an image in the same directory or folder ie like: <img src="pmsplogo.jpg" /> or <img src="images/pmsplogo.jpg" />  but NOT with my Xampp Wordpress install. (It works when just reading a .html file in Firefox.)

Might there be something weird that wordpress is doing here?

Comment: and have you tried path /images/your_img.jpg or images/your_img.jpg ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both src="images/pmsplogo.jpg" and src="/images/pmsplogo.jpg" ... 
Also I know the rest of the link is written correctly because it is displaying the alternate text.

Comment: and does it work? if not, it's a big mystery...and I would like to see the files, could you send me it?

Comment: yup - still doesn't work. and again, doing the same thing does work if I am just editing a .html file and displaying it in my browser.
Where should I send it?

Comment: idk, upload it somewhere and send me link

Comment: hmmm, not sure where or how I would do that at the moment. I can think on it, or you can email me at wheelers_cloud (at) yahoo (dot) com and I will send it to you as an attachment. thanks.

Comment: ok: http://www.filedropper.com/leftcolumn ... as you'll be able to see, it is a wordpress theme in its extremely early stages. (As is my coding experience.)

Thanks for taking an interest. We are being asked to avoid extended discussion here, so can you email me at the above address?

Comment: http://stepolabs.com/lab/stackguy/imgs.php , http://stepolabs.com/lab/stackguy/imgs.php.txt ... paths and php is working, in your php file is some different error and this is why is shows doctype, html head meta and title and then nothing else

Comment: I'm not following you here... is there some code I can change to make it work, or what should I do?

Comment: Your question about images and local urls is answered. Yes it can be "images/img.jpg" instead of "whole_path/images/img.jpg". Why your code is not working is not subject of this question. You shoule open new question and close this one.

Comment: Yes. Or post here on stack new question. I think that question about images was nicely answered :)

Comment: Here's the new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170419/img-src-correct-but-still-not-working-in-index-php