# Img Src correct, but still not working in index.php

Tags: html, wordpress, image, src

I believe I've correctly sourced an image in html for a (super-basic) wordpress theme I am developing; however it still does not display.

This dialogue:
[Img Src on local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102122/img-src-on-local-computer)
shows the process so far (whereby I've been reassured the html is correct.)

body of index.php:

```
<?php
    $main_menu_column_top = array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav-column-top',
        'container' => 'nav',
        'container_class' => 'alignleft widecol',
        'container_id' => 'column-main-nav',
        'depth' => 1
    );
?>

<div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.petermaurin.com">
        <img src="images/pmsplogo.jpg" alt="Peter Maurin Screenprinters"/></a>
    </div><!--logo-->

    <div>
        <ul>
            <h1><?php wp_nav_menu ( $main_menu_column_top ); ?></h1>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontent">

    <?php 
        if (have_posts()) :
            while (have_posts()) :
                the_post();
                the_title();
                the_content();
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>

    </div><!-- maincontent -->
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'main-nav-column-top' => 'Main Nav, Top of Header',
        'sub-nav-column-bottom' => 'Sub Nav, Bottom of Header',
        'footer-nav' => 'Footer Menu'
    )
);
```

css:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

p {
font-family: Times New Roman;
}

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: url(images/tshirttexture.jpg) left repeat-y #0099ff;
}

.leftcolumn{
    width:365px;    
    float:left;
}

.maincontent{
    background-color:green;
    margin-left: 375px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

... if anyone can take a look and let me know why my image ('pmsplogo.jpg' on line 26 of index.php) is not displaying, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Request URL:http://www.filedropper.com/leftcolumn
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found ??

Comment: Silly question but does images/pmsplogo.jpg` exist?

Comment: I've added the code to your question for you.  Please do this in the future, as questions on SO are supposed to be self-contained.  What happens if a user with a similar problem looks up this question, but the file is deleted?  They'll be out of luck.. hence, why you include the code in the question, not in a temporary file.

Answer (score 2):

In the img element the src attribute should look like this

```
<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/images/pmsplogo.jpg
```

So basically the full image url will be:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/images/pmsplogo.jpg" alt="Peter Maurin Screenprinters"/>
```

Comment: Ok! That did the trick! Thank you thank you!

... any chance you can explain to me why that works, but
src="images/pmsplogo.jpg" didn't? (Which works for me when it's on a regular HTML document not involving wordpress.)

Comment: The function `<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>` gets the template url. After this you manually add the location for your image inside the theme. In this case `/images/pmsplogo.jpg`. Note the `/` before `images`, is important. You can only use this function `bloginfo('template_url');` when you are doing Wordpress theming.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo 'dirname(__FILE__)'.'/images/pmsplogo.jpg'?>" />
```

Dont write with "http://www.yoursitename.com/" in PHP, they can't find source with it.

Comment: cut and pasted, the code you offered above doesn't produce the image. do I need to change it in some way?

Comment: Try change to `<img src="../images/pmsplogo.jpg" alt="Peter Maurin Screenprinters"/>`.