# Export multiple dataframes to html

Tags: python, dataframe

please I have a python script that produces multiple dataframes: df1, df2, ..., df10.
I would need ideally to export those dataframes all in one single pdf file but I realized that is quite complex. Hence, I'm trying to export the different dataframes into one single html file using the df.to_html() function.
However, how can I export all my datafames into the same html file?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df.head().to_html("testhtml.html")
df1.head().to_html("testhtml.html")
```

with the code above, the second .to_html instruction overrides the content of the first one, resulting with one single dataframe printed inside the html file.
Is there any way to "append" the dataframes inside the same html file?
Thank

Answer (score 6):

Use the `.to_html()` to get the string and add them:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: from numpy.random import randn
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
   ...: 

In [2]: with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
   ...:     _file.write(df.head().to_html() + "\n\n" + df1.head().to_html())
   ...:     

In [3]:                                                                                                                                     
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y
```

Now you will be able  to see both the tables in the same file:

[image]

```
$ cat a.html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
      <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1.565874</td>
      <td>1.612569</td>
      <td>1.213773</td>
      <td>-0.059322</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>-0.995417</td>
      <td>-0.279548</td>
      <td>0.204154</td>
      <td>0.803098</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>-0.188367</td>
      <td>-1.495322</td>
      <td>0.675200</td>
      <td>-2.432019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>0.776902</td>
      <td>2.642486</td>
      <td>1.858429</td>
      <td>0.024089</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>1.010742</td>
      <td>0.065047</td>
      <td>1.264571</td>
      <td>-0.982195</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>-1.381432</td>
      <td>-0.098652</td>
      <td>-1.002030</td>
      <td>0.133971</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>0.284307</td>
      <td>0.566509</td>
      <td>-0.640148</td>
      <td>-0.284037</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>0.412460</td>
      <td>-1.326584</td>
      <td>-0.297338</td>
      <td>0.531000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>-0.456548</td>
      <td>-0.354438</td>
      <td>-0.675962</td>
      <td>0.507228</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>-0.393275</td>
      <td>0.462753</td>
      <td>2.198363</td>
      <td>-0.042263</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: thank you! Would you know why the empty lines in the html files are not displayed once I open a.html?

Comment: You use <br> to denote empty line in HTML

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure if my follow-up question is still relevant. If it's not I apologize. I used the code you suggested and it works great. Hence, since using <br> allows me to enter empty lines between dataframes, I also tried the following code to add a png file but it doesn't work. Would you have any idea why?

with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write(df.head().to_html() + '\n \nTEST   <br> <br> <br> <img src="C:\Users\Python\Notebook Files\test_02.png"/> ' + df.head().to_html())

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102122/img-src-on-local-computer Most browsers need the file to start with `file://C:\Users\...`

Comment: in string '\' treat as escape sequence so when you enter "C:\Users" it thinks you want the escape sequence of \U. To solve this enter double `\\`.